# Issues editing posts, unable to type in the editor

Tags: bug, editor

The past few days I've been having issues editing posts. I'm able to add text to any line that already has text. If I try to add anything on an existing new line, nothing shows up in the editor, but the last character I typed shows up in the preview.

I'm using Safari 17.0 (19616.1.27.211.1) on Mac OS Sonoma. This does not seem to happen on Firefox on the same system.

[image: Image of missing character in editor while showing in preview]

Comment: Just to confirm: this is the old editor, not the beta Stacks Editor, correct?  (That is, this isn't in the Ask Wizard or an answer on MSO/MSE with the opt-in on)

Comment: @RyanM As far as I know, it's the old editor. It's on the posts of other users I've tried to edit on SO, and the screenshot I showed was this post.